# How to include a file which is not a module in Node.js (to make a module of it)?

Tags: node.js

**Purpose**: making a Node.js module or a Requirejs AMD module, from a plain old JavaScript file like this:

```
var foo = function () {};
```

I have **no control and I can't edit** `foo.js`.

Why`foo` is is a plain empty object inside the first `if`? How can I "include" a plain JavaScript file in my module? File `mymodule.js`:

```
(function(root) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object') { // Node.js
        var foo = require('./foo');

        console.log(foo); // { }
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { // RequireJS AMD
        define(['foo'], function () {
            return foo;
        });
    }
}());
```

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to do with the `RequireJS` portion of your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node modules loaded with `require` must populate an `exports` object with everything that the module wants to make public. In your case, when you require the file nothing is added to `exports`, hence it shows up as empty. So the short answer is that you need to modify the contents of `foo.js` somehow. If you can't do it manually, then you need to do it programmatically. Why do you have no control over it?

The easiest being that you programmatically wrap the contents if `foo.js` in the code needed to make it a proper module.

```
// Add an 'exports' line to the end of the module before loading it.
var originalFoo = fs.readFileSync('./foo.js', 'utf8');
fs.writeFileSync('./foo-module.js', originalFoo + "\nexports.foo = foo;");
var foo = require('./foo-module.js');
```

Comment: I solved using read + eval. Noo need to write the file back. I can't edit foo.js because it's a dependency (downloaded automatically).

Comment: This has spared me hours of work - my goal was to debug a specific test with mocha by loading all the needed globals, I can solve this by calling the test I want to debug, and feeding an array of needed file paths to a function that calls eval on them all

Answer (score 0):

You Could Try:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var foo = fs.readFileSync('foo.js', 'utf8') // Or request it somehow, just get it as a string

foo += "module.exports.foo = module.exports = foo;";

fs.writeFileSync('fooModule.js',foo);

var foo = require('./fooModule');

// foo() and foo.foo() are both the same
```

Note: This requires node.