# ReactDOM.render() unresolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

```
import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/dist/react-dom.min';
import {Alert} from 'reactstrap';

class AlertLine extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            visible: true
        };
    }

    onDismiss = () => {
        this.setState(
            {
                visible: false
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Alert color="success" isOpen={this.state.visible} toggle={this.onDismiss}>
                    <strong>Success!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
                </Alert>
            </div>
        );
    }
} 

ReactDOM.render(
    <AlertLine/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: Works with dom dev]

ReactDOM.render() works just fine with 'react-dom' for development. However, as soon as I try import minified 'react-dom.min' instead of 'react-dom', render() goes unresolved and nothing happens. I can't find render() from content assist(ctrl + space) neither.

I've installed react@15.6.1 and react-dom@15.6.1 with npm and they're on 'npm list'. Then I tried reinstall them but that didn't work.

Comment: Importing doesn't behave 1:1 with the file system. You can only import things from a file that the file explicitly exports (with the keyword `export`). If you want to minify your code, you should use a build tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Non-module

> Node modules loaded with require / import must populate an exports object with
>      everything that the module wants to make public.

[stackoverflow.com/a/14914442/6836839](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14914442/6836839)

`react-dom.min.js` is used as a simple js library, you can't `import` / `require`

## Install

Since you can't require / import, you need to load it as a normal `js` script:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script src="node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

## Use

```
// Just call it...
ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('root'))
```

## Note

> If you load React from a  tag, these top-level APIs are available on the ReactDOM global.

If you use ES6 with npm, you can write import:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

If you use ES5 with npm, you can write:

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you have to use `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` because `import` **doesn't mean "file import"**, it means **"ES6 module import"**.

To minify your bundle file, try [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) (if you're using `webpack`) or [minifyify](https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify) (if you're using `browserify`)

Comment: it doesn't mean "node.js module import", it just means "module import". It's part of ECMAScript 6, not Node.js.

Comment: I understand that, but in React case, `babel` will transform it to nodejs 's `require`. But thank you for your idea. Update it now.

Comment: Not necessarily. That depends on the babel settings. Babel is just an implementation detail, doesn't change what the syntax `import` means or how it behaves. Furthermore, modules are [available natively now](https://pawelgrzybek.com/native-ecmascript-modules-in-the-browser/) so we don't even need babel.

Comment: Great to know your information! Thank you. But I'm afraid we still need it for some next years to support some old browsers unfortunately :(

Comment: yes we do but that's beside the point, my point was to further explain why saying "nodejs module import" is not correct :). All that syntax means is that you're importing a module, you can't know with any certainty how the user's build system will transpille that or even if it will.

Comment: Agreed, thank you @nem035 for helping me understand more about the `babel` job :D

Comment: glad to help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Import name is not same as the component name which you are exporting.

When you Import a component in a common **Index.js** file and you are Importing a component(**import Header from './components/Header';**).

**Header** should be different from export default **headerComponent**; name