# How to use the npm module gs1-barcode-parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, gs1-ai-syntax

I want to extract the price value from the GS1 data martix QR code value using Nodejs.
Using the module

```
npm i gs1-barcode-parser
```

Tried the below throwing "parseBarcode" is not a function

```
const { parseBarcode } = require('gs1-barcode-parser');
let barcode = '\u001d01093393871222863922001405\u001d1522030631030006691095751410';
console.log(parseBarcode(barcode));
```

Comment: Based on its [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gs1-barcode-parser#how-to-use-it) and its [source](https://github.com/hprange/BarcodeParser), it's not a module and not meant to be `require`d, it's meant to be used in the browser. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913407/how-to-include-a-file-which-is-not-a-module-in-node-js-to-make-a-module-of-it

Comment: It can be imported (aka required), the source file just needs to be changed a bit. Check my answer below. Also your barcode doesn't parse. I included a parsable barcode in my answer that you can use to test with.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the modded module `gs1-barcode-parser-mod2`

```
const parser = require("gs1-barcode-parser-mod2")

let barcode = ']C101040123456789011715012910ABC1233932978471131030005253922471142127649716';
console.log(parser.parseBarcode(barcode));
```

Unfortunately your barcode seems to be invalid. You will need to decode from UTF-8 as that would result in `∞01093393871222863922001405∞1522030631030006691095751410` even then your barcode seems to have a missing prefix, called an Application Identifier or for short, AI (`]xxxxx..`).

A valid barcode example is given in the code snippet above.

[More info about application identifiers](https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes/application-identifiers)

Answer (score 1):

So your trying to import a module to a **CJS** environment, but the module is written to resolve as a front end JavaScript Module.

Fortunatly the package contains a single source file, with a single **IIFE** function.

#### THIS WILL MAKE IT AN EASY FIX!

Please note though, it is only one file & one function, but the file, and the function are really big for being a single file & a single function, so big, that it wouldn't be impracticable to add them as a snippet in a *Stack Overflow answer*, consequently; I have created a repository, and added the source code, *that works as a solution for this problem*, to the repository. I have outlined the changes that one needs to make to the module, to get it to work on the backend (in the Node **REPL**).

###### The files I added to my **REPO** should work for your current needs though. *Continue Reading*

---

##### To Convert The Module you Need to do the Following...

What you need to do is convert the package single source file into a Node module, which is very easy. The file is far to long to add to a Stack Overflow answer. So what I have done, is I have added the file into a public GitHub repository located [HERE](https://github.com/JAYD3V/Barcode-parser-for-node/blob/main/BarcodeParser.js).

##### Go to the link to the file I rewrote

- The file is a module conversion of [this file.](https://github.com/hprange/BarcodeParser/blob/master/src/BarcodeParser.js)
- Look at both files so you can see how I made the change.

In a nutshell, the author of the module wrote it using whats called an

##### IIFE: Immediately Invoked Function Execution

Its a type of function that is invoked immediately. The purpose of the function is to invoke at the very start of a script being loaded. IFFE's load before anything else, which is why he was using it to load his frontend module.

###### *The Entire Module is One function, and the whole thing is wrapped like the example below:*

```
(function (){ 
   // Function Logic Here. 
})();
```

###### Basically, what I did, is I unwrapped it, and appended a `module.export.BarcodeParser` assignment to the function.

**To reiterate:** Go Get the new File (or technically its written as a CJS module) from the [Repo I Created](https://github.com/JAYD3V/Barcode-parser-for-node/blob/main/BarcodeParser.js)

---

##### At This Point, Just Follow the Steps Below.

1. **Create a new Node.js project**, and make sure you execute `npm init` to generate a properly formatted `package.json` file.
2. **Test the converted module:** To test the file w/ the changes JayD3V implemented: Create a file in the same directory as the barcode parser, and add the following script to it.

```
const BarCodeParser = require('./BarcodeParser.js');

let barcode = ']C101040123456789011715012910ABC123�39329784711�310300052539224711�42127649716';

console.log(BarCodeParser.parseBarcode(barcode));
```

3. **Then execute the file using the `node` command.**

---

The README.md document in the repository has much of the information I added here in it.

#### Here is what it looked like when I ran it:

[image: Module Converted]

---

Answer (score 0):

you're using it on server-side (backend)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gs1-barcode-parser?msclkid=bb2e3c05cf5111ecabd6ce6b8aeb965a

as its documentation says it is a library
it also says that in order to use gs1-barcode-parser you have to add it in your application (on client side / frontend) as below:

```
<script src="./src/BarcodeParser.js"></script>
```

then you can use single function provided by it (`parseBarcode`) as follow :

```
try {
        var barcode = document.getElementById("barcode").value,
            answer = parseBarcode(barcode);
        // do something ...    
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```